# Mailkit IMap Client - How to parse reply from the rest of the email thread

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I am using Mailkit to build an IMap mail client. I am able to connect to an email account, get a list of MimeMessages and get the message Body, HtmlBody, TextBody etc.

In the case where emails are being replied to and therefore a conversation thread is being established; is there a way to get just the reply text from each reply without the rest of the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to get the body text and then filter out lines starting with `"> "`.

Lines starting with `"> "` is quoted text from a previous message in the thread.

Comment: Is this the case for all mails received from all email clients e.g. Gmail, Outlook etc

Comment: I can see the "> " character in mails received from a Gmail account but not from an Office365 account

Comment: The standard is to use `"> "`, so any client that doesn't use that isn't following the standard and you'll have to write custom logic for that client.Perhaps the Office365 client is sending HTML mail? In that case, it won't use lines starting with `"> "` - it'll use some sort of HTML syntax to do it (like maybe `<blockquote>` or something).